# Questions about CAN bus

Tags: pic, embedded, microchip, can

I am using the PIC18F2680 built-in CAN module along with CAN [MCP2551](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en010405) transceivers, and I am using the plib library for CAN2510 functions.
My question are:

1. Should we use twisted pair wires (like take CAN-Low and CAN-High wires and twist them)?
2. The second is more related to the CAN protocol - If two transmitters start transmitting at the same time and are assigned the same low valued ID as mask then who will win the arbitration and if not resolved, how to win the arbitration supposedly if I could write a code for it?
3. The third being: CAN works on CSMA/CD, so how is carrier sensing done?
4. How can we use MCP2551 in the Proteus ISIS simulation tool?
5. I am using the plib/CAN2510 library which is actually defined for PIC18Cxxx series. Can it be used for the PIC18F series or must I write my own functions for init, mask, filter, read, write, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CAN is a differential pair signal and could be twisted without issue.

The second and third questions go hand in hand. CAN uses a very interesting system. The bus has two states, dominant (0) and recessive (1). The bus idles in the recessive state. Every node on the bus can write to the bus and sense what is being written. When a packet starts everyone writes a dominant state to the bus to indicate the start bit. Then everyone starts writing their message address. For example suppose the first bit of the address is dominant. Every module that wrote a recessive state senses the dominant state and drops out. This goes on until there is only a single module left. The module that's left will finish its message.

That being said the CAN bus should never have two modules that can send a message with the same address. Speaking hypothetically if such an event did occur and both modules got through arbitration. Then the first instance where both a dominant and recessive state is written to the bus would be detected as a bus collision by the module who wrote the recessive state. From here you have two options as the designer of your own bus. Make the collision module shut up and let the other module finish transmission or make the collision module issue an error (hold the bus dominant for over 6 frames).

Comment: Thank you.My major problem was question number 2 and how to service that problem

Answer (score 3):

> 1.Should we use twisted pair wires (like take CANL CANH Wires and twist it).

Definitely, yes. Twisting wires resolves part of parasitic influence of the environment by using [common mode filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common-mode_signal). It also makes the twisted wires a more consistent transmission line.

> 2. If 2 Transmitters start transmitting at the same time and are assigned the same low valued ID as mask then who will win arbitration and if not resolved how to win arbitration supposedly if I could write a code for it?

CAN is a message-oriented protocol. The case you describe is two transmitters simultaneously sending the same message, which does not make much sense as a CAN message provides up to 8 data bytes to distinguish "talkers" so, in theory this situation should not happen.

> 3. Third being CAN works on CSMA/CD so how is carrier sensing done?

As per [Texas Instruments](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa101a/sloa101a.pdf):

> The CAN communication protocol is a carrier-sense, multiple-access protocol with collision detection and arbitration on message priority (CSMA/CD+AMP). CSMA means that each node on a bus must wait for a prescribed period of inactivity  before attempting to send a message. CD+AMP means that collisions are resolved through a bit-wise arbitration, based on a preprogrammed  priority of each message in the identifier field of a message. The higher priority identifier always wins bus access. That is, the last logic-high in the identifier keeps on transmitting because it is the highest priority. Since every node  on a bus takes part in writing every bit "as it is being written," an arbitrating node knows if it placed the logic-high bit on the bus.

The internal circuitry is designed so as to read the bus permanently, which makes the transceiver also read the data stream it sends on its own, see figure 4 in the document:

[image: Texas Instruments introduction to CAN, figure 4.]

If there is a difference between what it reads and what it sends, it immediately stops transmitting and enters an "error" state. The message is buffered for later retransmission.

I don't know about 4 nor 5 though.

Answer (score 2):

Answers to some of your question would be:

1. You need to twist the CAN-High and CAN-Low wires for reducing noise
2. I am not sure about the second question, but you could use the bit_error flag to restart the transmission.
3. And MCP2551 is not currently available in Proteus simulation tool.